# Merge multiple folder's contents into another folder

Tags: windows-10, ntfs

I was wondering if the following scenario is possible under Win10/NTFS:

I have two folders `A` and `B`, which I want to fill with the *contents* of the folders `X` and `Y`.

The folder structure of `X` and `Y` is

```
X\somefolderX\somefileX.blah
Y\somefolderY\somefileY.blah
```

Now, what I need is for B to include the *contents* of BOTH `X` AND `Y`, like this:

```
B\
  \somefolderX\somefileX.blah
  \somefolderY\somefileY.blah
```

Same concept for the folder `A` but with different contents.

NTFS junction points do not allow for the link to have the same name so while I get the redirection I'm missing out on the merging of the contents. Same for network shares and drive mapping.

I could just copy the contents and sync between `B`'s contents and the real `X` folder but I'd rather not have redundancy and syncing issues.

EDIT: need some sort of a folder as the top-most structure since I will use a program that operates on folders - which means that Windows Libraries or search filters wouldn't suffice =(

EDIT2: `X` and `Y` would contain about 200 folders max, content folder size (`somefolderX`) vary greatly between few kB and multiple GB.

UPDATE: Creating a symlink to a windows library succeeds but the link is inaccessible:

it results in either

`"the location is unavailable"` (when linking to `\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\libraryname`) or

`"directory name invalid"` (when linking to `\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\libraryname.library-ms` )

A direct path to the library is not recognized by the program

Comment: Did you consider a windows library? It depends on what you want to do but maybe that could help. Oh and what about folder `A`? It's never mentioned again? How many items do `X` and `Y` contain?

Comment: Updated the OP. I am using a program that operates on a folder list and manages the content of the folders as well as the folders themselves (contents of X and Y) and I'm pretty sure I can't give it a library or a windows search query as a path to work on. Except if i can map a library to a drive or network share... Gonna try

Comment: Symbolic link?  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: Sadly symbolic links do not allow merging from multiple sources, do they? If they would, this would be the second-to-none-solution for me. I tried to link `X` with `B` as target and then the same with `Y` but I cannot create link targets that has the same name as an existing target - thus no true merging is possible. Also, I cannot allow for additional folder depth inside `B` - this would break the programs compatibility

Comment: Sounds like it's a bit too much content in `X` and `Y` to just have a whole bunch of links in `B`. Is the Folder `B` frequently accessed? If not maybe just build a script to create the links a short while before `B` should be accessed or if it's just about having a common root create a link for `X` and `Y` in `B`? Right now it sounds like a copy job would be the easiest or the reversal of the logic. Spreading the content from `B` to `X` and `Y` could be easier?

Comment: Yeah, I've also thought that creating links for each `somefolderX` would be a bit overkill, that's why I didn't mention it. I might give the reversal logic a go but I guess i got onto something: A library seems to be  treated like a folder if it is accessed via a network share. I will test that one and report back.

Comment: Allright, I'm out of luck here - it is not the library that gets mapped as a network share, but instead the single folders inside the library - each one becomes a different share =(

Comment: There are 2 types of folders, real folders and virtual folders. Things that begin C:\MyPAth\... tend ot be real folders.  Things that begin {Some system resouce}\MyFolder tend to be 'virtual'.  The virtual work about 90% of the time.   Links work best when on real folders, not virtuals. The \appdata\roaming is a {system} type of path.  Use a usb drive or make your own folder structure on the c drive, and redo the symlinks.  Once get it working for a small set of test folders, there may be additional steps to expand to your real world case